# Open accordion using a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have a text field, in which I can filter the contents of the header of the accordion, as well as the content. I would like it when I am typing something, and if there is coincidence the accordion expands, but there is coincidence the accordions should be closed. how can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/3e9arqqe/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.pregunta">
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
 <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs | filter: search.pregunta">
    <div class="col-sm-11" >
      <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="faq.open">
          <uib-accordion-heading  >
              <span  ng-click="ignoreClick($event);" ><a  href='' click-to-edit item="faq" ng-model='faq.pregunta'   typeinput='textarea' >{{faq.pregunta}}</a></span> <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !faq.open}"></i>
          </uib-accordion-heading>
          <span click-to-edit item="faq" ng-model="faq.respuesta" >{{faq.respuesta}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </ui/div>
  </div>
 </uib-accordion>
```

I have an error when I replace the `is-open="faq.open"` with `is-open="search.pregunta?true:false"` and replace `ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !faq.open}"` with `ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': search.pregunta, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !search.pregunta}"`.

I am basically determining the expand/collapse state on whether the search text is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I summarize, you want the following behavior:

- accordion-group header matching the search.pregunta  -> OPEN
- accordion-group header not matching the search.pregunta  -> CLOSED

If it is the case, you should try :

https://jsfiddle.net/rtd6v41L/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.pregunta">
        <uib-accordion close-others="true">
           <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
              <div class="col-sm-11" >
                <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="faq.pregunta.indexOf(search.pregunta) !== -1">  
                   <uib-accordion-heading>
                      <span  ng-click="ignoreClick($event);">
                         <a href='' click-to-edit item="faq" ng-model='faq.pregunta' typeinput='textarea' >
                            {{faq.pregunta}}
                         </a>
                      </span> 
                      <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.pregunta.indexOf(search.pregunta) !== -1, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': faq.pregunta.indexOf(search.pregunta) === -1}"></i>
                  </uib-accordion-heading>
                  <span click-to-edit item="faq" ng-model="faq.respuesta" >{{faq.respuesta}}</span>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </uib-accordion>
```

In this way, the open/close of each accordion is linked to the search field.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I see a problem, I can not expand the accordion directly from the arrow. And the other problem is that I need it when I delete the content or write nothing, the chords finally close.

Comment: Look at the developer console, and all the time I get an error when I look for an item.

Comment: Yes that's a constraint of my implementation. Actually, if you want to be able to open/close manually (by clicking the arrows), you have to manage 2 modes to decide if a certain accordion should be opened or closed, according to the search + the history of clicks on the arrow. In this case, you should create methods in your controller and use it like this :   is-open="isOpen(faq.pregunta)"  . You are free to choose what to do in the function and deal with more complicated situations.